# Java: How to add whitespace before and after certain chars in a string

Tags: java, insert, stringbuilder

I've tried this to put white space between every '{':

```
String str = "t{esting";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i<str.length(); i++) {
        if(str.charAt(i)=='{'){
        sb.insert(i, " ");
        sb.insert(i+2, " ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
 }
```

It works fine for one '{':

t { esting

but if there are multiple '{' it does not work. for example: t{estin{g =

t { est i n{g where I want t { estin { g.

Thank you for having a look.

Comment: Your approach seems wrong. You should be iterating over the indexes of `sb` not `str`.  And when you insert or delete characters before the current position, remember to adjust the index to take account of that.   And as noted in the first answer, there are library methods for this kind of thing; e.g. `replace` and `replaceAll`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace every "{" by " { " like this:

```
String str = "t{esting";
String newStr = str.replace("{", " { ");
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code implements the fixes suggested in Stephen C's comment

```java
String str = "t{esting{";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) {  // use sb.length
    if (sb.charAt(i) == '{') {           // check the character in sb (not str)
        sb.insert(i,  ' ');
        sb.insert(i + 2, ' ');
        i += 2; // jump over the shifted `{`
    }
}
System.out.println("'" + sb.toString() + "'");
```

Output:

```
't { esting { '
```

However, `String::replace` or `String::replaceAll` methods are more suitable for such task.